# How to check for existence of record?

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following piece of code:

```
AccountMarket__c match = [select Id, Name, Account__r.Name, Market__r.Name 
                            from AccountMarket__c 
                            where Account__c =: opp.Account__c 
                                  and Market__c =: opp.Market__c Limit 1];
```

If there is no match for the query, the code blows up with `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`.  I would have thought, if the query returned nothing, the `match` object would simply be null and I could check for existence the next line.

If there is a match, the object is happily assigned the result.

Basically I am forced to query into a list and then check its size like this:

```
List<AccountMarket__c> matches = [select Id, Name, Account__r.Name, Market__r.Name 
                                     from AccountMarket__c 
                                     where Account__c =: opp.Account__c 
                                        and Market__c =: opp.Market__c Limit 1];

if (matches.size() == 0)
    system.debug('no matches');
```

This seems like a hack and I feel like I am missing something.
Is this the only way to check for existence of record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have the best possible way to accomplish this by querying into a list. Querying into a list is one way to avoid a QueryException. Another way to avoid the unhandled exception in code is to handle it, by putting your query into a try/catch block:

```
try { 
    AccountMarket__c match = [select Id, Name, Account__r.Name, Market__r.Name 
                        from AccountMarket__c 
                        where Account__c =: opp.Account__c 
                              and Market__c =: opp.Market__c Limit 1];
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle exception, test for query exception, whatever
}
```

Comment: Or, don't worry about the query. Simply perform whatever DML you want with the ID. If it's invalid you'll get an error you can catch or process through SaveResult.